# Unable to run ovrpredict in matlab online

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I want to run this on **online matlab** platform

```
 %predicting each letter using pretraind 'model'
 %y==13 does not contribute in any way to the result, just required
[recc,a,qwd] = ovrpredict(double(y == 13), X, model);

%converting class number to letter (ASCII), 1->A,2->B, etc
Handwritten_Text=char(recc+64)'
```

For predicting and showing output for my OCR but every time I run this it gives me an error

> Undefined function or variable 'ovrpredict'.
>
> Error in OCR (line 112) [recc,a,qwd] = ovrpredict(double(y == 13), X,
>   model);

Any suggestions of how to import LIBSVM to online matlab ?

Comment: put all the LIBSVM file in a new folder, then load this new folder using `addpath`

Comment: @obchardon can you post the code here ?